# Determinant of Jacobian and directional derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants, jacobians, operator-norms

I have a function $f: \Re^2 \to \Re^2$ and would like to understand why

$$|Jf(x)|=\max_\theta|D_\theta f(x)|\cdot\min_\theta|D_\theta f(x)|$$

that is, why the determinant of the Jacobian of $f$ at $x$ is equal to the product of the minimum and the maximum of the directional derivatives at $x$.

I think it must be a more general matrix fact, but I'm stuck at the moment.

Comment: Very briefly (I hope this makes sense): in polar coordinates, $\theta\mapsto D_\theta f(x)$ is an ellipse, and determinant of the Jacobian is (proportional to) the area of this ellipse

Comment: Where does this result come from? Do you know if there is a version for $n$ dimensions?

Comment: @JoseBrox I believe follows easily from$$\begin{align*}D_\theta f(x)&=\left.\frac d{dt}f(x_1+t\cos(\theta),x_2+t\sin(\theta))\right|_{t\leftarrow0}\\&=(\partial_{x_1}f_1(x)\cos(\theta)+\partial_{x_2}f_1(x)\sin(\theta),\partial_{x_1}f_2(x)\cos(\theta)+\partial_{x_2}f_2(x)\sin(\theta))\end{align*}$$

Comment: In $n$ dimensions similarly you get the unit sphere dilated in the $\theta$ direction by $D_\theta f(x)$, so you must get volume of an ellipsoid in that case.

Answer (score 8):

Any matrix $A$ can be written as $B.U$ where $B=\sqrt{AA^\top}$ is posititive semidefinite and $U$ is orthogonal (polar decomposition). Thus $|\det(A)| =|\det(B)|.|\det(U)|$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $B$ which are $\ge 0$ and which are also called the singular values or s-numbers of $A$. Your max.min formula multiplies the two singular values of the Jacobian.

Answer (score 2):

This is an addendum to the answer of Peter Michor simply to point out that the situation is even simpler since the Jacobean matrix is symmetric. It is thus just the basic fact in linear algebra---the determinant of a symmetric matrix is the product of its eigenvalues (so in the $2\times 2$ case the product of the larger and the smaller one). There is a direct extension to the general case using the minimax characterisation of the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix (for which see the classical text of Courant and Hilbert).

Comment: Not every Jacobian matrix is symmetric. Consider $f(x) = (x_2, 0)$.

Comment: If (and, locally, only if) $f$ is the gradient of a function $g$, then the Jacobian of $f$ equals the Hessian of $g$ and is thus symmetric.